# Implication of an inequality

Tags: inequality

We know that

$$|l(x+u)-l(x)|<1 \text{ for } x\geq y>0 \text{ and } u\in[0,1]$$

Why does:

$$|l(y+u)|<1+|l(y)|,x \in (y+1,y+2)$$

imply that

$$|l(x)| \leq 1 + |l(y+1)| \leq 2+|l(y)|$$

Comment: What part of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/140227) is not covered by @Joseph's answer below?

Comment: The part that Antonio Vargas explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for any inequality of the form $|a-b|<1$. Since $|a-b|=|b-a|$ we can say both that $|a|<1+|b|$ and $|b|<1+|a|$. Then combining the two statements give that $|b|<1+|a|<1+(1+|b|)=2+|b|$

Comment: Ok, that explains the second part of the last double inequality, but why does $|l(x)| \leq 1 + |l(y+1)|$ follow?

Comment: what is $l(x)$? an arbitrary function? or a linear function?

Comment: @Chris, if $x \in (y+1,y+2)$ then $x = y+1+u$ for some $u \in [0,1]$.  Your assumption then gives

$$
|l(x)| = |l(y+1+u)| < 1 + |l(y+1)|.
$$

Comment: Ahhh, got it now!