# Inequality - domain of a variable

Tags: inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implication of an inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140215/implication-of-an-inequality)

For $k>0,x\geq y>0$ the following holds 
$$|l(x)| \leq k+|l(y)|,$$

for $x \in (y+k-1,y+k)$.
Now, why does the same inequality hold also for $x \in (y,y+k)$?

Edit: The different posts where part of the same proof. The objective was to show that a function $l(x)$ is bounded if $l(x+u)-l(x)|<1 \text{ for } x\geq y>0 \text{ and } u\in[0,1]$.

The proof (answers to the previous posts are included) goes as follows:

Let $x=y,\ y+u=z$ for every $z \in (y,y+1)$ and we have $$|l(x+u)-l(x)|=|l(z)-l(y)|<1.$$

Using the triangle inequality we have:

$$|l(z)|=|l(z)-l(y)+l(y)|\leq |l(z)-l(y)|+|l(y)|<1+|l(y)|.$$

Using the same argument we have for $x \in (y+1,y+2)$:

$$|l(x)| \leq 1+|l(y+1)| \leq 2+|l(y)|.$$

For positive $k$ we have:

$$|l(x)| \leq k+|l(y)|,$$

for $x \in (y+k-1,y+k)$.

Now the thing is, that I need this to be true for $x \in (y,y+k)$ as well and I do not understand why it is so.

Comment: What is $l(x)$?

Comment: Suppose $x \in (y,y+1)$.  Then $|l(x)| \leq 1 + |l(y)| \leq k + |l(y)|$.  Can you fill in the rest?

Comment: Why is this not a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/140215/6179)?

Comment: @Didier, I suspect it would take at least as much work to explain why it is a duplicate as to just solve it.

Comment: @Gerry I see no reason to encourage OPs to ask over and over basically the same question.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not convinced OP knows it's the same question. Perhaps the equivalence can be explained to OP.

Comment: I've edited the question.